# Angularjs + Jquery Draggables testing issue with Karma and Jasmine

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I have an angular app that needs a small bit of jquery for complex ui drag and drop operations. To do so I am using jQuery ui draggables.

They work fine, but then I don't know very well how to apply karma/jasmine unit testing to the controllers anymore.

All my other controllers are tested without a problem but this particular controller that has jQuery now inside is the one is giving me problems.

I am receiving this karma error:

```
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.9 server started at http://localhost:9876/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X)]: Connected on socket c8iF8rN90zbXSoEYRJzC
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Mac OS X) ERROR
ReferenceError: Can't find variable: $
```

I heard that it is better to move the jQuery bits to directives. Could you please guide me in this case?

I am creating tabs in this way inside of my controller. Currently the UI works well, but as I said, it is not testable.

```
$scope.addSortables = function (){
    //ordering locations
    $(".dummy-widget .days-container .locations").sortable({
        "stop" : function (ui, event){

            refreshLocations(ui, event);

            PreviewManager.enableTabs();
        }
    });
}
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3):

Angular uses [jqLite](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element) instead of jQuery, but it will happily use jQuery provided that you load it before you load angular. Once you do this you won't need to rely on the global `$`, `angular.element` will become your [jQuery handle](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html).

So, did you remember to load jQuery in your Karma config? It should look something like the following:

```
    // in karma config
    files: [
        'vendor/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
        'vendor/angular/**/*.js',
        'src/app/**/*.js',
        'spec/**/*.spec.js'
    ],
```

Another thing is that you should try to avoid doing direct DOM manipulation in your controller; use a directive instead. There's a good tutorial on writing angular directives [here](http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/directives.html).

Hope this helps.